# Java issue with updating a unique variable, Simulation 1 line 1 queue

Tags: java, queue, simulation

I'm having a problem with a variable not updating when its supposed to. I also am not sure where to update this variable as it does not fit into any of the if statement tests in my code. YOU MUST UNDERSTAND, that all I need fixed is where the variable `peopleCompleted` gets updated when **the first person to enter** is done. In my code you'll see where this **first person** is arriving, taking his place as the `curServed` and then being printed without being added to the queue holding everyone else who **is in line**. You'll notice that `curServed` gets changed in the `serviceComplete()` because it handles everyone else *IN THE QUEUE*. Below is my code and sameple output that is incorrect because of `peopleCompleted` not being updated for that first person. Basically, I really need help with knowing where to update his completion in the first place. This is a Simulation of a One Line One Queue. I am a beginner/student

**CODE**

```
public boolean arrival()
  {
     Customer myCust = new Customer(curTime);
     if(curServed == null) // If no one being served
     {
        curServed = myCust; // myCust is served
        peopleNoWait++;
        return true;
     }
     else if(!q.isFull())
     {
        q.add(myCust);
        peopleThatHadToWait++;
        return true;
     }
     return false;
  }

  public Customer serviceComplete()
  {  
     if(q.isEmpty())
     {
        curServed = null;
     }
     else
     {
        curServed = q.remove(); // Remove next from customer queue
        peopleCompleted++;
        sumOfWaitTime += getWaitTime();
     }
     return curServed;
  }
```

*THESE BELOW HANDLE THE SIMULATION ABOVE*

```
private void doArrival()
   {
      boolean check = sim.arrival(); // Do an arrival
      if(check == false)
         System.out.println("Customer arrived but left immediately"
               + " because the line was full (too long) at time " + 
               sim.getTime() + ".");
      else
         System.out.println("A customer entered system at time " + 
               sim.getTime() + "." + " Number waiting in queue is "
               + sim.getNumWaiting() + ".");
   }

   private void doServiceComplete()
   {
      if(sim.notBeingServed() == true)
      {
         System.out.println("No customer is being served at the present time"
               + " of " + sim.getTime() + ".");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.print("Customer " + sim.getCurCust().toString() + 
               " finished at time " + sim.getTime() + ". Number waiting" + 
               " is ");
         System.out.println(sim.getNumWaiting() + ".");
      }
      sim.serviceComplete();
```

**Methods that return the vals below**

```
public int getNumWaiting()
  {
     int total = peopleThatHadToWait - peopleCompleted;
     return total;
  }

  public int getTotalServed()
  {
     return peopleCompleted;
  }
```

**Sample output where error is:**

1. Customer C1/T2 finished at time 7. Number waiting is 2. // Should be 1
2. Customer C2/T6 finished at time 7. Number waiting is 1. // Should be 0
3. Customer C3/T7 finished at time 13. Number waiting is 5. // 4
4. Customer C4/T7 finished at time 16. Number waiting is 4. // etc
5. Customer C5/T8 finished at time 16. Number waiting is 3.
6. Customer C6/T8 finished at time 17. Number waiting is 2.
7. Customer C7/T9 finished at time 17. Number waiting is 1.
8. The number of people served is 7. // Should be 8
9. The number of people served is 7. // Should be 8

COMMENTS:

These are the lines causing issue. The number waiting and the number of people
served are the ones that are incorrect. It is because of the the lack of the 
peopleCompleted being updated with that first person after he is completed, which 
according to your advice, is not done in serviceComplete()

Comment: Hi user3386412, a good way to get your question answered quickly and effectively on stack overflow is to abstract your question away from minutiae of your implementations details. This involves you endeavoring to understand exactly what you're wanting to do (rather than asking how to do some specific thing that may or not be how to solve your problem, as you are doing here). This helps us help you.

Comment: Its kind of hard to put this into a general realm, because I can't really get general about this question. I understand what you're saying.

Comment: When you do your best to cut the explanation and the code down as much as possible and the answers come much faster :-)

Comment: I'll have to remember that. Thank you @theSilentOne . I guess I'll leave the question up, but for the future I'll try to make things more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because of this code block here.

```
private void doServiceComplete()
{
  if(sim.notBeingServed() == true)
  {
     System.out.println("No customer is being served at the present time"
           + " of " + sim.getTime() + ".");
  }
  else
  {
     System.out.print("Customer " + sim.getCurCust().toString() + 
           " finished at time " + sim.getTime() + ". Number waiting" + 
           " is ");
     System.out.println(sim.getNumWaiting() + ".");
  }
  sim.serviceComplete();
}
```

When you get to `sim.getNumWaiting()` your people waiting will be one less than you're expecting. `sim.serviceComplete()` has `peopleCompleted++` which is performed AFTER you print your results. You should move this to the beginning of the method, or somewhere else logical, before `sim.getNumWaiting()` is called.

Example:

```
private void doServiceComplete()
{
  sim.serviceComplete();

  if(sim.notBeingServed() == true)
  {
     System.out.println("No customer is being served at the present time"
           + " of " + sim.getTime() + ".");
  }
  else
  {
     System.out.print("Customer " + sim.getCurCust().toString() + 
           " finished at time " + sim.getTime() + ". Number waiting" + 
           " is ");
     System.out.println(sim.getNumWaiting() + ".");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed exactly what I ended up figuring out about a week ago. Thank you though for this, I didn't get a chance to see it, but this is correct. :)